# Mysql Select statement with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi this is my select sql query and its result :

**SELECT line,machine_type, COUNT(*) as linewise FROM dr_scan GROUP BY machine_type,line ORDER BY `dr_scan`.`line` ASC**

| line | machine_type | linewise |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Button Attach | 4 |
| 1 | Double Needle | 1 |
| 1 | Flatlock | 1 |
| 1 | Single Needle | 1 |
| 5 | Button Attach | 2 |
| 5 | Flatlock | 1 |
| 5 | Double Needle | 1 |

**I want to make this table as below**

| line | machine_type | linewise |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Button Attach | 4 |
|  | Double Needle | 1 |
|  | Flatlock | 1 |
|  | Single Needle | 1 |
| 5 | Button Attach | 2 |
|  | Flatlock | 1 |
|  | Double Needle | 1 |

Comment: Why would you want a `NULL` line? At the database level, that data should be included (otherwise you cannot actually GROUP BY those fields). If you want to format a table for displaying elsewhere, do that in application code.

Comment: You haven't clearly explained the logic, and there's no logical ordering to your rows.

Comment: This question seems to be about formatting the output, but this should really be done in the presentation layer (GUI), not in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lag to get the previous line sort by line and put it in a case statement such that if the value of lag is equal to line than display blank.

```
insert into @tmp(
line ,  machine_type ,  linewise 
)
values(1,'Button Attach',   4)
,(1,'Double Needle',    1)
,(1,'Flatlock', 1)
,(1,'Single Needle',    1)
,(5,'Button Attach',    2)
,(5,'Flatlock', 1)
,(5,'Double Needle',    1)

select 
case when lag(line) over(order by line)=line then '' else cast(line as varchar(10)) end line
,machine_type,linewise
from @tmp
```

output:

```
line    machine_type    linewise
1   Button Attach   4
    Double Needle   1
    Flatlock    1
    Single Needle   1
5   Button Attach   2
    Flatlock    1
    Double Needle   1
```